# Show large values in terms of power of ten

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working in d3.js and I have a problem.I am making a graph using the tutorials and examples. My issue that on Y axis of my graph I have very large values like (120000000000) which are dynamic. I am unable to show these values on a limited space So is there a way to show these large values in power of 10 like 12X10^10 or any other way using d3?

Right now I am using the scale like this

**Power scale**

```
y = d3.scale.pow().exponent(0.3).domain([0, maxvalue ])
                                .range([Height, 0]).nice();
```

**log scale**

```
y = d3.scale.log().clamp(true).domain([0.1, maxvalue])
                               .range([height, 0]).nice();
```

**Linear scale**

```
y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, maxvalue])
                     .range([height, 0]).nice();
```

**This is common for all scale**

```
yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(6, tickFormatForLogScale)
                                   .orient('left');
```

Any help in showing the values properly will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: the domain of x values in a log-y graph is usually a lot "less" than the domain of the y values, because a "large" domain 1-10million: get compressed by the log() function. So I'm guessing `maxvalue` for the x domain is way too much in your graph.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has the method toPrecision:

```
 var anumber=123.45
 anumber.toPrecision(2) //returns 1.2e+2
```

Comment: Thanks @shaun5 but this function doesnt seeems to to working with d3.js :(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make something that looks like a log y  linear x graph after modifying the example at: http://d3-example.herokuapp.com/examples/area/area.html

I changed the following:

```
   var data = d3.range(500).map(function(i) {
     return {x: i , y: i*i};
     //return {x: i / 39, y: (Math.sin(i / 3) + 2) / 4};
   });

  var y = d3.scale.log().clamp(true)
       .domain([1, 220000])
       .range([height, 0]);

  var x = d3.scale.linear()
       .domain([0, 500])
       .range([0, 900]);
```

It seems unintuitive, but he `height` variable and the 900 literal define how big the rendered graph is. This may be due to how data is defined (parametrized function). To make this work, you have to tweak the domain of  map(function(i){...}). The i variable will be given the values [ domain[0], ...., domain[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlXDl.png)] and both x and y are calculated with the corresponding math expression in the map function.

I don't know how useful this will be to you, because you haven't shown the rest of your code. If you are still confused, try plotting a few log-scale graphs with http://www.geogebra.org/ to get a general feel of how they work.

Here is what I get: 
[image: logarithmic y scale]

Comment: Thanks alot for your detailed answer.....But I am some how unable to understand as I am new to d3.Here are my few queries that 1)Are you changing the data to be be plotted if yes then why ? 2)Also what about linear and power scale ?

Comment: I made the data disply the graph of x² becasue the sinus function that was in the example never shows to any high values and because you didn't provide your function (data set) to be plotted. I'm not sure what you mean by power scale.